# How to export more than 200000 records from a table to CSV in SQLDeveloper

Tags: r, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which has close to 2000000 records in the table .
I want to export all these records from Table to a CSV file .
But the CSV file is allowing me only a max of 200000 files at a time . 
My ultimate goal is to take all these records and form a dataframe in R for further analysis.

Comment: 2 million rows is a lot of data, maybe you might even have a hard time loading that into R in one go.  Have you considered exporting a random subset of data, say 10%?

Comment: I havent considered it yet . But i would require all the data for analysis . Is there a way to break it into chunks and then export it or load it ?

Comment: Have you thought about using the `RODBC` library to connect directly with Oracle?

Comment: Yes i tried . But to use this i would have to add a data source in ODBC Data Source Admin . I am entering my server details and trying but the connection is failing during Test Connection. (Error : Connection Timeout)

Comment: Well these are basically your options; you either import CSV files or directly bring the entire table into a data frame via ODBC.

Comment: How would i do it using CSV Files ? I am stuck with the limitation of 200000 records on export

Comment: probably a duplicate - see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091567/how-to-export-large-amount-of-data-using-sql-developer-oracle

Comment: What do you mean your CSV file has a limit? Do you mean SQLDev won't let you export the entire data set to CSV?

Comment: Have you tried with spool?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer has no limit on the size of the CSV we export.

Here's an example of a table to CSV to 2,500,000 records.

```
CREATE TABLE so_2m (
       x   INT,
       y   DATE
);

BEGIN
       FOR i IN 1..2500000 LOOP
              INSERT INTO so_2m VALUES (
                     i,
                     SYSDATE
              );

       END LOOP;
END;
/

commit;

select count(*) from so_2m;

Table SO_2M created.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Commit complete.


  COUNT(*)
----------
   2500000
```

And now let's query and export to CSV

[image]

And now let's watch the export and then do a count of lines in the file.

My CSV has 2,500,001 lines. The first line is the Header list of column names.

[image]

My 2018 Mac Mini with Oracle VirtualBox running Database 18c EE and SQL Developer version 18.4 generated this file in about 2 minutes.

Comment: `insert into so_2m select rownum, sysdate from dual connect by level <= 2500000` might save you some lines of code

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald yeah I know but I was too busy not thinking :)